# TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len() Codeacademy

Tags: python

Hi I'm a beginner working with code academy. I've asked this question in several venues and searched everywhere, can't figure out the problem.

The goal is to verify that users have answered the question. Here is my code

```
print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'

raw_input("Enter a word: ")
original = raw_input
if len(original) > 0:
    print original
else: 
    print "empty"
```

When I execute the code and enter a word, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

I've tried many variations of the code, I don't understand what is happening. I really appreciate any and all input.

Comment: You are using Python 2.x, not Python 3.x. I corrected your tags.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to get the length of the `raw_input` *function*. The actual result of the function call on the previous line you ignored.

```
>>> len(raw_input)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

You want to store the output of the function call in `original` instead:

```
original = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
if len(original) > 0:
    print original
else: 
    print "empty"
```

Comment: You guys are amazing. So quick. so accurate. Nothing like python forums.